# Swift: Checking UIImage failable init

Tags: swift, uiimage

I want to check if an image exists, but in the failable init... I can do it ugly, but really I want to know if `self == nil` is possible...

```
extension UIImage {

    convenience init?(_ name:String) {
        let image = UIImage(named:name)
        guard image != nil else { Assert("image \(name) missing yo"); return nil }
        self.init(named: name)
    }
}
```

cleaner but doesn't compile

```
extension UIImage {

    convenience init?(_ name:String) {
        self.init(named: name)
        if self == nil { Assert("image \(name) missing yo") }
    }
}
```

static func isn't as fun as init

```
extension UIImage {

   static func with(_ name:String) -> UIImage? {
        let image = UIImage(named:name)
        if image == nil { Assert("image \(name) missing yo") }
        return image
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your time

** EDIT **

perhaps I need both?

```
extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(_ name:String) {
        self.init(named:name)
   }
}

extension Optional where Wrapped == UIImage {
    init?(_ name:String) {
        self.init(name)
        if self == nil {
            Assert("image \(name) missing yo")
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: You are writing an extension for `UIImage` and `UIImage` cannot be nil since it is not an optional.

Comment: It definitely can be?? If you UIImage(named:"something_incorrect") you'll get nil back

Comment: It cannot: If you mark it like this: `UIImage?` then it can be nil. Try setting a variable of type UIImage to nil in playgrounds. It won't compile.

Comment: `var image:UIImage? = nil` compiles fine

Comment: that's what i said: then your variable "image" is of Type `Optional` and not `UIImage`

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand... I want a failable init where I can also check for the success of the init

Comment: Maybe this is what I want... but I mean... write some code maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if i get your question correct. But i think you want something like that: (let me know if it helps or why not)

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == UIImage {

    init?(_ name:String) {
        self.init(name)
        if self == nil {
            Assert("image \(name) missing yo")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks, except I want `self.init(named:name)` ?